# in middle of installation qt-everywhere show me this error:

Tags: qt, gcc, fedora

> ..........................g++ -o
>   "/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake" project.o
>   property.o main.o makefile.o unixmake2.o unixmake.o mingw_make.o
>   option.o winmakefile.o projectgenerator.o meta.o makefiledeps.o
>   metamakefile.o xmloutput.o pbuilder_pbx.o borland_bmake.o
>   msvc_vcproj.o msvc_vcxproj.o msvc_nmake.o msvc_objectmodel.o
>   msbuild_objectmodel.o symmake.o initprojectdeploy_symbian.o
>   symmake_abld.o symmake_sbsv2.o symbiancommon.o registry.o epocroot.o
>   qtextcodec.o qutfcodec.o qstring.o qtextstream.o qiodevice.o qmalloc.o
>   qglobal.o qbytearray.o qbytearraymatcher.o qdatastream.o qbuffer.o
>   qlist.o qfile.o qfsfileengine_unix.o qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.o
>   qfsfileengine.o qfsfileengine_iterator.o qregexp.o qvector.o
>   qbitarray.o qdir.o qdiriterator.o quuid.o qhash.o qfileinfo.o
>   qdatetime.o qstringlist.o qabstractfileengine.o qtemporaryfile.o
>   qmap.o qmetatype.o qsettings.o qlibraryinfo.o qvariant.o qvsnprintf.o
>   qlocale.o qlinkedlist.o qurl.o qnumeric.o qcryptographichash.o
>   qxmlstream.o qxmlutils.o
>
> The target system byte order could not be detected! Turn on verbose
>   messaging (-v) to see the final report. You can use the -little-endian
>   or -big-endian switch to ./configure to continue.

I have fedora 21 version 32 bit. and my system is little endian when i write lscpu in command line. but now i don't know what can i type to continue configuration
what is this meaning last paragraph?what can i do know?
help me please
this is my command line :

```
echo yes | ./configure -prefix /opt/Qt4.7 -opensource -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -no-webkit -qt-libtiff -qt-libmng -qt-mouse-tslib -qt-mouse-pc -no-mouse-linuxtp -no-neon
```

Comment: What was your complete `configure` command?

Comment: # Echo yes |. / Configure-prefix / opt/Qt4.7-opensource-embedded arm-xplatform qws / linux-arm-g + +-no-webkit-qt-libtiff-qt-libmng-qt-mouse-tslib-qt- mouse-pc-no-mouse-linuxtp-no-neon

Comment: Would you edit your post and put the `configure` command in a <codeblock>?  The comment looks a bit garbled.

Comment: when i add my path /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/ and export it . this error not apear.But in some sites i see some one use this parameter in config command. -little-endian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all files type "*.o" from qmake folder in qt folder. then run configure command again